# How to list files 8 characters long and no extension, in 1 line using only ls/grep?

Tags: text-processing, grep, ls

I'm trying to list all files with 8-character names and with no extension.

My problems begin with files such as: "test.txt", where the "." is in the middle.

I've already tried, doing ls and redirecting the output to a file, then using grep to get the files I need, but I was wondering:

Is this possible to do this in 1 line using ls/grep/redirection/extglobs etc?

Answer (score 2):

You can use grep to match for any 8 characters except `.`:

```
 $ ls | grep '^[^.]\{8\}$'
```

Or if piping is a problem:

```
 $ find . -regex '.*/[^.][^.][^.][^.][^.][^.][^.][^.]'
```

Or in many shells simply:

```
 $ ls -d [^.][^.][^.][^.][^.][^.][^.][^.]
```

Comment: that involves piping, do you think its impossible without it?

Comment: Piping is pretty common, what is the concern?

Comment: it wasn't taught to my class when this question was asked of us, so I'm wondering if it can be done without it.

Comment: Shouldn't `ls -d [^.][^.][^.][^.][^.][^.][^.][^.]` work in most shells?

Comment: @steeldriver, sadly not in the brain dead shell I am currently using, but that is a sad tale for some other time.  However, duly noted and edited accordingly.  Thanks.

Comment: Please note: [parsing ls is bad idea and generally frowned upon](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: `[^.]` should be `[!.]`.  The filename globbing patterns use `!` instead of `^` to negate a character class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `?` to match any one character in most shells:

```
$ GLOBIGNORE='*.*' eval "ls -d ????????"
```

The `GLOBIGNORE` variable guides the globbing to, in this case, avoid file names with `.` in them, and the `-d` flag avoids listing contents when matching to directory names. Use `man bash` for more details.

Comment: yes, but that will include "."

Comment: True. You're happy with the pipe answer above, but I'll edit mine for the sake of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]
```

all filenames that are 8 characters long and alphanumeric only (no hyphens, periods, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Since [parsing ls is generally a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) , here's two alternative solutions - one  in python as one-liner and another in shell loop:

```
$ python -c "import os,sys;[sys.stdout.write(f+'\n') for f in os.listdir('.') if len(f) == 8 and '.' not in f]"
TEXTFILO
deadline
FILENAME
diskman2
Pictures
emptydir
ud_indie
strategy
EET 4330

$ for f in * ; do ! [[ $f =~ '.'  ]] && [[ ${#f}  -eq 8  ]] && echo "$f" ; done
deadline
diskman2
EET 4330
emptydir
FILENAME
Pictures
strategy
TEXTFILO
ud_indie
```

Syntax of both is the same - we itereate over files in current working directory, and using two logic checks for whether there is `.` in filename and whether filename is equal to 8 characters, determine which filename to print.

Note that the `[[` syntax can be used with `bash`,`zsh`, and `ksh`

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all the input guys, after some hours I figured out what I was trying to do.

$ ls -d !(!(???????)|*(*.*))

your extglob has to be set for this to work.